# How to use selectInput as a reactive across modules

Tags: shiny, module, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, golem

I am currently building a shiny app using golem framework and attempting to use modules however I am struggling with connecting modules. My current paired-down app consists of 3 basic modules: 1) determines data selection of a user, 2) plots figures, and 3) global UI. My issue is how to structure the modules so that when the user selects inputs in module 1, the data is filtered based on those selections and then made available for plotting in the next module. The plot module is then using an if/else statement to determine which plot should be shown based on the inputselect used in the data selection module. I have the select inputs in a side panel and not within the plot module for a reason, so I'd like to keep those separate. Any help, even if a basic structure of how this could work, would be great!

Below is the code I've tried, and the error lies in how I am communicating across modules. However, I'm just not sure how to fix it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

data<- expand.grid(
  year = 1993:2005,
  species = c("Chinook", "Steelhead"),
  rear_type = c("Hatchery-origin", "Natural-origin"),
  doy = 90:180)
data<-data %>%
  mutate(SAR = rnorm(n(), mean = .05, sd = .01))



mod_dataselect_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(

    #select species
    selectInput(inputId = ns("select_spp"),
                label = "Select species",
                choices =  c("Chinook", "Steelhead"),#data.pred$species
                selected = unique(data$species),
                width = "200px",
                multiple = T),

    #select rear type
    selectInput(inputId = ns("select_rear"),
                label = "Select rearing type",
                choices = c("Natural-origin", "Hatchery-origin"),
                selected = unique(data$rear_type),
                width = "200px",
                multiple = T),

    # prompt to select all years or by year
    selectInput(
      inputId = ns("year_display"),
      label = "View by",
      choices = c("All Years", "Year"),
      selected = "All Years"
    ),
    uiOutput(ns("year_picker"))
  )
}

mod_dataselect_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    # Render the UI for the year picker
    output$year_picker <- renderUI({

      ns <- session$ns


      if (input$year_display == "Year") {
        pickerInput(
          inputId = ns("select_years"),
          label = "Select Year(s)",
          choices = unique(data$year),
          selected = 2000,
          options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
          multiple = TRUE
        )
      } else {
        NULL
      }
    })

    # Reactive for year_display
    year_display <- reactive({
      input$year_display
    })

    filtered_data <- reactive({
      if (input$year_display == "All Years") {
        data %>%
          filter(
            species %in% c(input$select_spp),
            rear_type %in% c(input$select_rear)
          )
      } else if (input$year_display == "Year" && !is.null(input$select_years)) {
        data %>%
          filter(
            species %in% c(input$select_spp),
            rear_type %in% c(input$select_rear),
            year %in% c(input$select_years)
          )
      } else {
        NULL
      }
    })

  })
}


mod_SAR_plot_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(

    plotly::plotlyOutput(outputId = ns("SAR_plot"))

  )
}

#' SAR_plot Server Functions
#'
#' @noRd
mod_SAR_plot_server <- function(id, data){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    #    Retrieve reactive values from mod_dataselect_server
         dataselect_reactives <- mod_dataselect_server("dataselect_1")
         filtered_data <- dataselect_reactives$filtered_data
         year_display <- dataselect_reactives$year_display

    output$SAR_plot <- plotly::renderPlotly({

      # Filter data based on user selection
      if (dataselect_reactives$year_display == "All Years") {

        ggplotly(ggplot(dataselect_reactives$filtered_data, aes(x=doy, y=SAR))+
                   geom_point() + facet_grid(rear_type ~ species))

      } else if (dataselect_reactives$year_display == "Year") {

        ggplotly(dataselect_reactives$filtered_data, aes(x=doy, y=SAR))+
                   geom_point() + facet_grid(rear_type ~ year + species))
      }
    })
  })
}


app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(

    fluidPage(
      shinydashboard::dashboardPage(

        ## Sidebar content - used as a navigation menu to each tab
        sidebar = shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
          shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(
            # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
            id = "tabs",
            shinydashboard::menuItem("Plots", tabName = "figs", icon = icon("chart-line")),
            div(id = "tabs_filter",
                conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabs == 'figs'",  mod_dataselect_ui("dataselect_1"))
            )
          )
        ),
        body = shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
          shinydashboard::tabItems(
            shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "figs",mod_HydroSurv_ui("HydroSurv_ui_1"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
}


app_server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filtered_data <- reactive(mod_dataselect_server("dataselect_1"))

  mod_SAR_plot_server("SAR_plot_1", filtered_data())
  mod_SAR_table_server("SAR_table_1", filtered_data())
}
```

Comment: You do not need a conditionalPanel as `Shinydashboard` only displays the information on the selected tab on the sidebar.

Comment: wow. I spent way too much time making that work and you are absolutely right. I do not need to make it a conditional panel. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the reactives in a list from the first module. Then pass it on to the plot module as a reactive object.  Then access the value with `()` inside the plot module. Try this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

data<- expand.grid(
  year = 1993:2005,
  species = c("Chinook", "Steelhead"),
  rear_type = c("Hatchery-origin", "Natural-origin"),
  doy = 90:180)
data<-data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(SAR = rnorm(n(), mean = .05, sd = .01))


mod_dataselect_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    
    #select species
    selectInput(inputId = ns("select_spp"),
                label = "Select species",
                choices =  c("Chinook", "Steelhead"),#data.pred$species
                selected = unique(data$species),
                width = "200px",
                multiple = T),
    
    #select rear type
    selectInput(inputId = ns("select_rear"),
                label = "Select rearing type",
                choices = c("Natural-origin", "Hatchery-origin"),
                selected = unique(data$rear_type),
                width = "200px",
                multiple = T),
    
    # prompt to select all years or by year
    selectInput(
      inputId = ns("year_display"),
      label = "View by",
      choices = c("All Years", "Year"),
      selected = "All Years"
    ),
    uiOutput(ns("year_picker"))
  )
}

mod_dataselect_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    # Render the UI for the year picker
    output$year_picker <- renderUI({
      req(input$year_display)
      
      if (input$year_display == "Year") {
        pickerInput(
          inputId = ns("select_years"),
          label = "Select Year(s)",
          choices = unique(data$year),
          selected = 2000,
          options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
          multiple = TRUE
        )
      } else {
        NULL
      }
    })
    
    # Reactive for year_display
    yr <- reactive({
      input$year_display
    })
    
    filtereddata <- reactive({
      if (input$year_display == "All Years") {
        df <- data %>%
          dplyr::filter(
            species %in% c(input$select_spp),
            rear_type %in% c(input$select_rear)
          )
      } else if (input$year_display == "Year") { 
        df <- data %>%
          dplyr::filter(
            species %in% c(input$select_spp),
            rear_type %in% c(input$select_rear)  
          )
        if (!is.null(input$select_years)) df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(year %in% c(input$select_years))
      } else {
        df <- NULL
      }
      df
    })

    return(list(filtered_data = filtereddata, year_display= yr))
    
  })
}


mod_SAR_plot_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    
    plotly::plotlyOutput(outputId = ns("SAR_plot"))
    
  )
}

#' SAR_plot Server Functions
#'
#' @noRd
mod_SAR_plot_server <- function(id, data){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    #    Retrieve reactive values from mod_dataselect_server
    # dataselect_reactives <- mod_dataselect_server("dataselect_1")
    # filtered_data <- dataselect_reactives$filtered_data
    # year_display <- dataselect_reactives$year_display
    
    output$SAR_plot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
      dataselect_reactives <- data
      filtered_data <- dataselect_reactives$filtered_data()
      year_display <- dataselect_reactives$year_display()
      p <- NULL
      # Filter data based on user selection
      if (year_display == "All Years") {
        
        p <- ggplotly(ggplot(filtered_data, aes(x=doy, y=SAR))+
                   geom_point() + facet_grid(rear_type ~ species))
        
      } else if (year_display == "Year") {
        
        p <- ggplotly(ggplot(filtered_data, aes(x=doy, y=SAR))+
          geom_point() + facet_grid(rear_type ~ year + species))
      }
      p 
    })
  })
}


app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    
    fluidPage(
      shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        ## Sidebar content - used as a navigation menu to each tab
        sidebar = shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
          shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(
            # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
            id = "tabs",
            shinydashboard::menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
            shinydashboard::menuItem("Plots", tabName = "figs1", icon = icon("chart-line"), 
                                     mod_dataselect_ui("dataselect_1"),
                                     shinydashboard::menuItem("Display Plots", tabName = "figs", icon = icon("chart-line"))  ### need to select this tab to display plots
                                     )   #,
            # div(id = "tabs_filter",
            #     conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabs == 'figs'",  mod_dataselect_ui("dataselect_1"))
            # )
          )
        ),
        body = shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
          shinydashboard::tabItems(
            shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "home", p("Hello") ),  ## display other info on the home page
            shinydashboard::tabItem(tabName = "figs", 
                                    # mod_HydroSurv_ui("HydroSurv_ui_1"),
                                    mod_SAR_plot_ui("SAR_plot_1") #,  mod_SAR_table_ui()
                                    )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
}


app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  filtered_data <- mod_dataselect_server("dataselect_1")

  mod_SAR_plot_server("SAR_plot_1", filtered_data)  ### filtered_data is reactive
  # mod_SAR_table_server("SAR_table_1", filtered_data)
}

shinyApp(ui=app_ui, server=app_server)
```

Comment: That works! Thanks for the edits. It seems pretty simple but I just wasn't making that connection. Much appreciated.